# Is there any limitation on the length of the classpath in java?

Tags: java, command-line, jar, classpath, manifest.mf

I tried to set classpath from command line for a java class

```
java -cp lib1.jar;lib2.jar;lib3.jar MyProgram
```

The above code threw runtime exception as it has further dependency with other jar file when I added the jar file it is unable to recognize the Main class in MyProgram class and threw

```
Error:Main method not found in class MyProgram,please define the method as public static void main(Stirng[] args)
```

The length of the strings lib1 ,lib2 and lib3 is about 400 characters.
Is there any limitation on the size of the classpath which can be set from command line .I tried setting class path using Manifest file as well but still it is throwing same exception.

Comment: Does `MyProgram` contain a main method?

Comment: Is `MyProgram` on the classpath?

Comment: Yeah it has main method but after adding lib4.jar it didn't recognize it till then it was able to recognize

Comment: There is at least the limitation of your command interpreter; it's pretty high though, so it is unlikely that you hit this limit.

Comment: It says it find the MyProgram but cannot find the main method, therefore, it means it reaches to MyProgram.jar

Comment: Make sure your MyProgram is a public class, or else it will be protected by default.

Comment: Does `lib`4.jar` also contain a class named `MyProgram`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot test the program that you have written,so one solution by observing the details provided could be-
java –classpath ${CLASSPATH}  MyProgram
**Note:** here you would have to set CLASSPATH variable before using it.